# Regex extract data from String

Tags: php, regex

I have following string structure

```
abcd("Some value",
  "Some data", Value);

asd("xyz", "abc");


xyz("Values",
    "sesef",
    adfak);
```

I want to extract this as below

```
array[0]="abcd("Some value",
  "Some data", Value);"

array[1]=asd("xyz", "abc");

array[2]=xyz("Values",
    "sesef",
    adfak);
```

In above sample code spaces between the functions is not fix & newline inside the function is also not fix.

I tried using the following regex but it is not working

```
preg_match_all("/.*\((.+?)\);/is", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: Are you only trying to capture statements which end with a semicolon? What happens if the source text contains a function definition instead of just a bunch of loose statements?

Comment: Basically i want to capture all functions in array